# Get variable from NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, variables

In my app I want to reduce the amount of if checks so I decided that this way is the best but I am just not sure how to do it.

So I have a bunch of #define 's, they are: state1, state2, state3, etc...

Anyway I have UIButtons and the image of the button with tag 1 is determined by state1, etc...

Anyway I now I got to the point where I do something like this:

```
NSString *variableString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"state%i", theButton.tag];
```

So now how do I get the variable like state1 or state2 or state3 from the NSString that I just got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a NSDictionary with strings like @"state1", @"state2"...as the keys and the matching references to the image as the object for the key.

Comment: I can't do it that way, I must do it this way. I know this is possible.

Comment: I'll be interested to learn how.  I'm only used to it in languages like Perl and in shell scripting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
[self valueForKey:variableString];
```

**However** if the string value in `variableString` does not match a variable or a property this call will throw an exception. You can catch the exception with an `@try { ... } @catch ...` block. If you don't catch and handle the exception your app will fail.

Comment: Can't use this, I need a way to somehow turn my NSString into a variable. I am not looking for a workaround (I don't mean to sound harsh)

Comment: @iBradApps - Are you wishing to dynamically create variables with names taken from strings? I understood you are trying to access an existing variable, and `valueForKey` and the corresponding `setValue:forKey` for exactly that - you have a "variable" accessed via a string. (There is also `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` and `valueForUndefinedKey:` which you can implement to handle missing variables.) I'm intrigued about what you are actually trying to do as I obviously misunderstood...

Answer (score 0):

```
const int value = [[someString substringFromIndex:nCharsToTrim] intValue];
```

alternatively, you can avoid unnecessary string creation by accessing the character values `-[NSString characterAtIndex:]`

(and you should probably avoid using 0 as a valid state value in this scenario)

Comment: I'm confused about how this would work. Lets say we have a NSString that says: state1 (but in NSString form), this code above would convert the variable, value to be state1 in a variable form?

Comment: my example just converts it back to the `tag`. you would need to use the `tag` value to identify the view among the views in question (of course, that tag must be unique).

Comment: That won't work. I need not just the number but the text before it to. I am starting to get the idea that this isn't possible with Obj-C.

Comment: It's possible for objects with ivars (and/or properties) if you use KVO. E.g. `[self valueForKey:@"ivar1"]` would work. But for 'normal' variables it seems hard. (For ivars/props of an object, there's also the possibility of using selectors, but avoid it if you can. :p )

Comment: well, you could just use the tag as an index to one or more arrays -- also note that your approach is uncommon. this stuff (in a general definition) is certainly possible with the language -- however, it's somewhat awkward and again, alternate approaches are more typical.